# Must declare the scalar variable "@tabvar"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

```
declare @departmentid int;
set @departmentid = 1;
declare @tabvar table (id int, name nvarchar(100))
begin
insert into @tabvar 
select DepartmentID, Name
from HumanResources.Department where DepartmentID = @departmentid;
print @tabvar
end
```

It shows

> Must declare the scalar variable "@tabvar".

Comment: Gordon did such a nice job formatting your code, too bad you put it back to a wall of text style.

Comment: And now the original error has been removed - which means the answer doesn't match the question

Comment: You can't print a table variable

Comment: From @DaleBurrell comment, use `select * from @tablevar` instead of print.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is

```
print @tabvar.id
```

Remove this and the code will work.

The following is equivalent functionality:

```
print @departmentid;
```